# Spring / IntelliJ doesn't clear session data on stop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I ran in a weird situation I never had before.
I've got a spring boot application running on intelliJ on ubuntu 18.

My spring boot application runs in a dev environment connected to a h2 in memory database. I have a session based login with spring security.

The weird thing is if after I stopped and restarted the application I am still logged in. And even if I completely restart IntelliJ the session is  not cleared. Even the database keeps its state and is not getting dropped.
Only if I restart the whole system everything will be cleared.

Inside my application.properties there are no special properties set.
Everything's on default.

If I stop the application the following console output comes up:

```
2018-12-22 11:11:19.385  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@73abcbfa: startup date [Sat Dec 22 11:11:00 CET 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12e6f48a
2018-12-22 11:11:19.391  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-12-22 11:11:19.391  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-12-22 11:11:19.395  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-22 11:11:19.395  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2018-12-22 11:11:19.415  WARN 10000 --- [      Thread-35] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
2018-12-22 11:11:19.417  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-22 11:11:19.419  INFO 10000 --- [      Thread-35] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Comment: please provide your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: I'm having exaclty the same weird situation: with an old cookie (which is just a key) I have the same session (=same spring security context) as before the restart. Did you find out why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-1.3.0-m3-release-notes

> Update Tomcat, Jetty and Undertow to serialize session data when the
>   application is stopped and load it again when the application
>   restarts. Persistent session are opt-in; either by setting
>   persistentSession on the ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer or by
>   using the property server.session.persistent=true (Persistent sessions
>   are enabled by default with Devtools).

In spring boot 2, the property is:

`server.servlet.session.persistent=false # Whether to persist session data between restarts.`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about web login via browser (or REST-client). Also I suppose you're using default web security settings.
Then your login request creates a cookie with session id which is returned to browser and is being used in next requests until you close browser.